# Why is rust's rayon taking longer with Arc<Mutex<anyhow::Result<()>>>?

Tags: rust, parallel-processing, rayon

I am trying to parallelize my codes using the crate `rayon`. The process is to read a file, process it and output the processed file.

I want to take note of the result of the processing of each file such that I have an `Arc<Mutex<Vec<anyhow::Result<()>>>>` which I lock and push each `anyhow::Result<()>` resulting from the processing of one file.

```
fn main() {
    let (mut files, _) = utils::get_files_from_folder(input_folder)?;

    let results = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<anyhow::Result<()>>::new()));

    files.par_iter_mut().for_each(|path| {
        
        if let Some(extension) = path.extension() {
            if extension == "txt" {
                let result = redact::redact_txt_and_write_json(path, &regex_vec, &output_folder); // processing done here
                results.lock().expect("`results` cannot be locked").push(result); // lock the mutex and push done here
            } else {
                eprintln!(
                    "{}INVALID EXTENSION: {} - Not yet implemented",
                    *RED_ERROR_STRING,
                    extension.to_string_lossy(),
                );
                std::process::exit(1);
            };
            ()
        } else {
            eprintln!("{}EXTENSION not found", *RED_ERROR_STRING);
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
    }); // end of for_each
    println!(
        "{:?}", results.as_ref()
    );
    Ok(())
}
```

My question is: why is it apparently, that with locking, it takes longer than without locking?

With locking:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1m 34s
```

Without locking:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.30s
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"without locking"*? Please provide code for both cases.

Comment: When multiple threads are trying to access a mutex at the same time, they have to "wait" until it gets unlocked to be able to take over. Sometimes mutex isn't the best solution to use across threads.

Comment: Please provide [MRE]s, especially for timing claims. Your code does not even compile; you can't return an `Ok(())` from a `main()` without return value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your minimal example is quite convoluted and not reproducible, so I rewrote it to demonstrate the problem you are having:

```rust
use std::{
    sync::{Arc, Mutex},
    time::Instant,
};

use rayon::prelude::{IntoParallelRefIterator, ParallelIterator};

struct SomeResult(u32);

fn do_some_processing(arg: u32) -> SomeResult {
    SomeResult(arg * 2)
}

fn main() {
    let input_data = (1..10000000).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let t_start = Instant::now();
    let results = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::<SomeResult>::new()));

    input_data.par_iter().for_each(|value| {
        let result = do_some_processing(*value);
        results
            .lock()
            .expect("`results` cannot be locked")
            .push(result); // lock the mutex and push done here
    });
    let t_end = Instant::now();

    println!("Result item count: {}", results.lock().unwrap().len());
    println!("Time taken: {} ms", (t_end - t_start).as_millis());
}
```

```
Result item count: 9999999
Time taken: 116 ms
```

A `Mutex` is not the optimal data structure here. Locking means that the parallelization you achieved through the use of `rayon` has to be serialized again at the point of adding the result into the `Vec`, which becomes a major bottleneck. Only one thread can do `push` at the same time, all the other threads wait inside the `.lock()` function for the one thread to finish, until the next thread is allowed. Basically, they are constantly waiting for each other.

`rayon` has a solution for this usecase. Its parallel iterators support `.collect()`, which is the same as putting every item into the vector, just without the lock and highly parallelized.

With `.collect()`, I can reduce the time in my example down from `116 ms` to `3 ms`.

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

use rayon::prelude::{IntoParallelRefIterator, ParallelIterator};

struct SomeResult(u32);

fn do_some_processing(arg: u32) -> SomeResult {
    SomeResult(arg * 2)
}

fn main() {
    let input_data = (1..10000000).collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let t_start = Instant::now();
    let results: Vec<SomeResult> = input_data
        .par_iter()
        .map(|value| {
            let result = do_some_processing(*value);
            result
        })
        .collect();
    let t_end = Instant::now();

    println!("Result item count: {}", results.len());
    println!("Time taken: {} ms", (t_end - t_start).as_millis());
}
```

```
Result item count: 9999999
Time taken: 3 ms
```

Comment: I sincerely apologize for my lack of reproducible codes for this question. I'll do better the next time. Thank you for spending time to write a minimum viable example that absolutely captures the essence of my question and your answer completely resolves it! Thank you!

Comment: So I should not be using `for_each` but instead I should use `.map()` so that I can return `anyhow::Result` type in the closure and `.collect()` 'to' the `results`. Yeah, I guess the limitation of `for_each` (i.e. closure must return unit type) forced me to use the convoluted `Arc<Mutex<...>>` initially.

Comment: @Jim Exactly. `.map()` is the same as `.for_each()`, just with the difference that it can propagate a value out from each iteration.

Comment: Note that even for the `Mutex` version, the `Arc` is not needed: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=bae05a01b0edd12543755853757928b6).

Comment: @Jmb You are absolutely right. Although the `Arc` is not the bottleneck in this case, so I didn't bother.

Comment: @Jmb @Finomnis Thanks both. Why is `Arc` not needed? Is it because `rayon` does not do multithreading so atomic reference counting is not needed here?

Comment: @Jim It's because you can pass non-mut references repeatedly into nested scopes, as long as those scopes are known to end before the original variable is destroyed. `Arc` is only needed if the place you pass it to has to actively keep the variable alive; in the `rayon` case, the compiler can prove that the variable stays alive until the end of `main()`, and `rayon`'s threads are definitely finished before the end of `main()`. (That's at least the high-level view, the low level view of how lifetimes work exactly is a little more nuanced)

Comment: The reason I talk about references here is because there is no `move` keyword on your closure, so everything it references from the outside is automatically done by reference. Otherwise you would have to `.clone()` your `Arc`, which you don't do; `Arc`s are pretty much pointless if not at least two of them exist for the same object. Otherwise you can simply use references.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Finomnis; just a short follow up question: 1. I happened to need to use `par_mut_iter` which sends a `&mut value` to which thread, I guess in this case, an `Arc` is still not neccessary because `.collect` will 'ensure' all references are dropped before the `main()` is dropped?

Comment: @Jim I think you mix up concepts here - you never needed `Arc` for the **argument** of the closure. `par_mut_iter` only has an effect on the argument, not on the variables that the closure references from the outside directly. Whether or not you use `.collect` also has no effect on the `Arc` thing - but if you use `.collect()` you don't need to reference the outside `Vec` in the first place, so I'm not sure what you are trying to say here.

Comment: Now I get it, because I am not moving the `Mutex` into each thread, I am only passing in a reference of `Mutex` into each thread and each thread is guaranteed to be dropped before `main()` gets drop, hence there is no need to do atomic reference counting to ensure `results` can be referred to for any thread however long they might live.

Comment: @Jim Exactly. That's it.

Comment: @Finomnis Sorry. Just want to be sure: all threads are dropped before `main()` is dropped because of `.collect()`?

Comment: @Jim No, it's because that's how `rayon` works. `rayon`'s threads are attached to the `par_iter` object, which gets dropped at the end of `main()`. `.collect()` just moves that point to an earlier time, because `.collect()` consumes that `par_iter` object, destroying it in the process.

Comment: @Finomnis, now I fully get it; thank you!

Comment: @Jim The only reason it **doesn't** work with normal [`std::thread::spawn()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.spawn.html) is because the [`JoinHandle`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/struct.JoinHandle.html) objects they produce do **not** actually destroy the thread if they are dropped, so the thread could outlive `main()`. That said, there is [`std::thread::scope()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) which allows you to spawn scoped threads that behave the same as the `rayon` versions.

Comment: @Finomnis Thank you for your follow up explanation!